# Which are the best suitable volume types in kubernetes to store host configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

Can we use single volume across multiple Nodes in read-only manner and that way save on the storage required for hosting Configuration in kubernetes.
If yes then which is the best sutaible volume type for same?

Comment: ConfigMaps are designed for your use case. Why not [volume mount a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume) into a container?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by single volume but, you can use [persistentVolumeClaim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#persistentvolumeclaim) which should be created with [Access Modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) `ReadOnlyMany`

> - ReadOnlyMany – the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes

You need to keep in mind that not all [Types of Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes) are available in that `Access Mode`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage configuration in Kubernetes is by creating a ConfigMap objects and mounting them as volumes/folders into pods.

Mounting ConfigMap as volumes:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume

Good luck.